# Angular 2 hidden works with boolean, but not object property

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an element I want to show or hide based on the property of an object, as well as some values from this object to be displayed within the element.

If I do `shouldShow: boolean = true;`, and use `[hidden]="!shouldShow"`, it works fine.

However, If I try `options: any = { shouldShow: true, value: 'some value' }` then use something like `<elem [hidden]="!options.shouldShow">{{options.value}}</elem>`, nothing shows. If I inspect the element, I can see that it still has the hidden attribute, and no contents.

Comment: So when you use an object to store the boolean what happens exactly? Is your desired behavior for it to receive the hidden attribute - based on the value of the shouldShow boolean?

Comment: Does `options.value` show if you remove the `[hidden]` attribute?

Comment: @DanielCooke That is correct, it is hidden initially and then on a trigger from a user action, the `value` in the object is updated and `shouldShow` is set. @Razzildinho No, `{{options.value}}` does not show anywhere. I've verified that the value is set by logging to console.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the behavior you are referencing. If you have a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cgejpngj7Ce0LtAvxQuc?p=preview). What is the tag you are applying this too? What is <elem>?

Comment: @DanielCooke I managed to fix it using your plunker. I was using a `ViewChild` which had the same selector as the variable name, which appears to overwrite it.